# Erro Postgresql - sql:4862: ERROR: syntax error at or near "textoGrande"

Tags: postgresql, sintaxe

Boa noite, pessoal.

Estou tentando importar para meu banco de dados Postgres um sql de um banco de dados externo e estou sofrendo o seguinte erro:

```
.sql:4862: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "textoGrande"
```

A estrutura do sql é a seguinte:

```
-- PARA BANCO DE DADOS ORACLE, EXECUTAR A LINHA ABAIXO
-- SET DEFINE OFF;
DECLARE
textoGrande CLOB;
BEGIN
textoGrande := '';
INSERT INTO SGT_CONSULTA.CLASSES VALUES ('2','','','','ProcCivTrab',NULL,'','',textoGrande,'N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','S','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','C','marivaldodantas',to_date('04/09/2012','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),NULL,'pedro.amorim');
textoGrande := '';
INSERT INTO SGT_CONSULTA.CLASSES VALUES ('5','','','','STJ',NULL,'','',textoGrande,'N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','C','pedro.amorim',to_date('15/10/2018','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),NULL,NULL);
textoGrande := '<p align="justify" class="Artigo" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial; font-size: small; text-indent: 35px;">
    Art. 318. &nbsp;Aplica-se a todas as causas o procedimento comum, salvo disposi&ccedil;&atilde;o em contr&aacute;rio deste C&oacute;digo ou de lei.</p>
<p align="justify" class="Artigo" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial; font-size: small; text-indent: 35px;">
    Par&aacute;grafo &uacute;nico. &nbsp;O procedimento comum aplica-se subsidiariamente aos demais procedimentos especiais e ao processo de execu&ccedil;&atilde;o.</p>
'; [...]
END
-- SET DEFINE ON;
```

O sql dá um erro de sintaxe informando que não existe esse campo `textoGrande`. Alguém sabe como ultrapassar esse erro?
O código utilizado no terminal para a importação é: `psql -h localhost -d databasename -U username -f dump_dados_postgres.sql`
O banco de dados é público e a versão completa está no link: https://www.cnj.jus.br/sgt/versoes.php.

Comment: Na tabela de erros do PostgreSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html não existe o código de erro 4862. Qual versão do PostgreSQL? Qual Sistema Operacional? Creio que o tipo de dado CBLOB não existe no PostgreSQL.

Comment: Talvez o comentário "-- PARA BANCO DE DADOS ORACLE, EXECUTAR A LINHA ABAIXO" seja uma dica.

Comment: A versão do Postgres é a 10.12. Estou utilizando o Mint 19.3. Realmente o tipo `CLOB` não existe no Postgresql, mas apenas no Oracle. Mas mesmo eu apagando essas linhas iniciais o erro persiste. `psql:/home/alison/Downloads/dump_dados_postgres.sql:54793: ERROR:  column "textogrande" does not exist
LINE 1: ...,'S','S','N','S','N','N','CPC 2015','1.036, § 1º',textoGrand...`

Comment: Então nos comandos `INSERT`  substitua as ocorrências de `textoGrande` por `''`.

Comment: Mas se eu fizer isso vou perder os dados que estão na variável `textoGrande`. O responsável pelo banco deixou esse campo como uma espécie de variável porque ele tem um texto realmente grande e o `insert` poderia ficar ilegível. Pensei em substituir manualmente, como vc falou, mas o BD tem mais de 93.000 registros e centenas de insert's com essa variável. Fica inviável.

Comment: Então substitua o tipo `CLOB`por um tipo aceito pelo PostgreSQL, `text` talvez?

Comment: Também já fiz isso, mas não deu certo. O erro continuou. Inclusive o logo do erro que postei aí acima nos comentários já ocorreu com a alteração do campo `CLOB` para `TEXT`.

Comment: Estranho, na versão 10 não consta este código de erro https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/errcodes-appendix.html.

Comment: Debugando por aqui percebi que esse código antes do nome error não é um código de erro do postgres, mas a linha do sql que está disparando o erro, entendeu? A saída do erro mesmo é só `ERROR: column "textogrande" does not exist`

Comment: Dei uma olhada no arquivo de dados e creio que você pode colocar os dados do arquivo dentro de um bloco anônimo. Veja: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html